# How to consume/pip install a custom Python package artifact in another build pipeline in Azure Devops?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, build, pip, azure-artifacts

So I have build a custom Python package which has the end-purpose of serving as a shared Python library across multiple Azure repositories. This package is available as an Azure Devops artifact.

However, I can not find a way in which I can connect to the feed when building the repositories, which is of course needed to pip install the package as to make the library available to the repository that is being built.

I do get the package installed locally by adding a pip.conf with the right credentials to one of my local virtual environments. I would think that adding this pip.conf file to my Python github repositories and then pip installing the package during the build would work.

However, when I install locally I have to login to azure via browser to authenticate, which is of course not possible from within a build pipeline.

I cannot find any way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve in the Azure docs. Is there any way to make this work? Or else, is there a better way to set up a shared python library in Azure Devops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to consume/pip install a custom Python package artifact in another build pipeline in Azure Devops?

There is a task [**Python pip authenticate**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/pip-authenticate?view=azure-devops#versions), which provides authentication for the pip client that can be used to install Python distributions:

[image]

Then we just need to create a **Service connections** to connect the feed:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I understand. Can I ask where you can get this 'python pip authenticate' window? When I  click on the task `python pip authenticate' within a build pipeline, it only gives me the option to choose the feed from 'my feeds', but nothing with personal access tokens etcetera...

Comment: @Tim, You could let the option `My feeds (select below)` as null, then click the manage on the option `Feeds from external organizations`, then create a Service connections to add personal access tokens.